# Stotra and mantra reciting positions: sitting at one place or otherwise?

Tags: scripture, krishna, mantras, stotra, prayer

I have had this doubt for ages about the best way to get the benefits of the stotras and the mantras that we recite. But is it necessary to sit down at a place and recite them both or can we do our household chores and still recite them?

Comment: in mantra sadhana according to my Gurudeva, the goal is to become one with the sound of the mantra.To do so requires you to still your body completely, because only when your body is still can the mind become still, and only with a still mind with complete awareness can one merge with mantra and reach that state of supreme one pointed concentration.Sitting down in various poses like padmasana and siddhasana helps your harness the various vayus and gain control over various involuntary actions of your body which in turn help you still your body.

Comment: So it really depends on your goals, if its to merge with the sound of the mantra and reach the state of supreme one pointed concentration, you being in perfect communion with deity of your mantra, no other option than to sit down and do your sadhanas.If your are doing it like a feel good exercise, do it however you want.My guru also says in initial stages of sadhana you need to sit down and meditate as your mind is not tamed yet, but in the final stages you are already meditating every moment, because your mind is tamed and is doing all karma detached from the material world!